# docker volume mount directory in windows

Tags: docker

I'm using docker 1.13.1 in Windows 10 with Hyper-v

and I've a volume

```
C:\autotestDocker\plat1>docker inspect plat1_logscore
[
   {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
             "com.docker.compose.project": "plat1",
             "com.docker.compose.volume": "logscore"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/plat1_logscore/_data",
        "Name": "plat1_logscore",
        "Options": {},
            "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Is it possible to found in the filesystem the "Mountpoint" directly?
I cannot change the mount method (I cannot mount it to another folder), I have these settings and I cannot change them...

I've tried with an ubuntu machine and if I try to do

```
cd  /var/lib/docker/volumes/plat1_logscore/_data
```

I can modify or copy file inside the correct volume.

I would do the same with windows, but I'm just not able to locate the mount directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount the volume in another container and modify it from there.

```
docker run -it --rm -v plat1_logscore:/target ubuntu
```

Select whatever image you'd like to use in place of ubuntu. Then your plat1_logscore volume will be accessible under /target and you can edit it with any commands included inside of your container.

Alternatively, you can copy the files out to your host with a command like:

```
docker run -it --rm -v plat1_logscore:/source \
  -v c:/Users/Marco/plat1_logscore:/target \
  busybox cp -avr /source/. /target/.
```

You can reverse the volumes in the command to copy files back into your named volume from your host.